# Read and write Excel file with colored text in R

Tags: r

I want to read data from Excel to R. Some data in that file is coloured RED (for identification). I want to read this data in R with colored texts and then write in EXCEL SHEET with the coloured text as well. Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to determine the text color of any given cell when reading in the data from a spreadsheet. However, when writing the data, you can write text in color with the [`openxlsx` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) (check out the vignettes on the linked page). See the `fontColour` argument of the `createStyle` function. You can then use the `addStyle` function to add this style to specific cells of a worksheet.

Comment: You need to look into the `tidyxl` package. That one can handle colors, data validation rules for importing. For writing I suggest `openxlsx` package.